# graphics are not running properly

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, hp

I recently installed Ubuntu 14 on my pc HP xw6400.
but the graphics are very slow.
video songs don't play properly. I tried installing different drivers for graphics card but none of them worked out.
my graphics card in NVIDIA QUADRO NVS 285.

Any suggestions about what might the problem be?

Comment: What are the results of running the command: `ubuntu-drivers devices`? Sometimes (usually) if you run this command it will identify the recommended graphics driver for your system. Wait for at least a minute after entering the command so that it can scan your hardware.

Comment: yes i tried this command.
it says nvidia-graphics-304 as recommended driver for my graphics card
i installed this driver but still the same problem.

Comment: i hav installed the following driver   <br/>
using NVIDIA legacy binary driver-version 304.123 from nvidia-304(open source)

Answer (score 0):

You've just got a [really ancient card](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=Quadro%20NVS%20285) and **no matter what you're going to do**, *it's going to be slow as the proverbial tortoise*. I would just install [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) (or upgrade my hardware)...

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.  :-(

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)